# Inserting to a database from listview with OnOptionItemSelected

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

I need some help. Still a bit new to android programming, and I'm not sure if this can be done.

The gist of what I'm doing: I'm currently grabbing data from a RESTful API, that spits data back as a json array. I get the data and pump it into a table, then I use an adapter and display all the data in a listview.

The data looks like this (replace x with data):

```
[{
id: xxx,
number: "xxxxx",
title: "xxxxxxx",
definition: "xxxxxxx",
status: "xxxxx",
name: "xxxxx"
},
```

Here's the problem: From the listview, I want to take the data, and onItemSelect, I want to insert the selected data into a separate table. The user can select one or more listview, and then click a menuItem from onoptionitemselect and it would insert the data into the table.

I have two main questions:
1. I am currently using this code in the setOnItemClickListener:

```
String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

It pumps out as an array. Is it possible for me to parse from the array each individual element? (based on the data, I want to pull out data for id, number, title, etc)
2. I'm not sure if this works, but after I have the selected items, can I use the onOptionsItemSelected menuitem to tell the app to insert the data into the new table?

This is all I have right now:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.menu_favorite){
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Thanks for any and all of your help. This has been a great learning experience, and I hope to learn more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My way of handling this would be to maintain an arrayList of ids which are selected.

Inside onItemClick, move the position to this arrayList.

Then inside onOptionsItemSelected, take the arrayList contents and use this to push the data to DB